# How to send html data to flask without form

Tags: python, jquery, python-3.x, flask

i know you can easily send form data to flask using calls like `$.ajax()` in jquery but what I need is a way to send data to a flask server using an element, say a `<p>` tag.

For example:
test.html

```
<p data-rep='testentry' class='qtemp'>Entry00</p>
<p data-rep='testentry01' class='qtemp'>Entry01</p>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.qtemp').on('click',function(){
        var layout = $(this).data('rep');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'workstation',
            type: 'POST',
            data: layout
        });     
    });
});
```

main.py

```
@app.route('/workstation',methods=['GET','POST'])
def workstation(data):
    layout = data

    return render_template('station.html',target=layout)
```

Running This App:

1. Doesn't render the template `station.html`
2. Doesn't print the `layout` variable which contains the data sent (I added a print statement and it didn't work,even tried writing it to file)

What i've Tried:

1. In `index.js`, replace `data: layout` with `data: JSON.stringify(layout)` then in `.main.py` , replace `layout = data` with `layout = request.args.get('data')`.

needless to say, all of this doesn't work

**NB: Using an html form is not an option**

Comment: You don't have a `success` callback in your Ajax request, so the response is just silently ignored

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify your `ajax` to ensure that you are receiving `JSON`ified results from the Python route. Also, in order to store data returned from an ajax call, you must access the values by key name using `flask.request.args`:

In `index.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.qtemp').on('click',function(){
    var layout = $(this).data('rep');
     $.ajax({
      url: "/workstation",
      type: "get",
      data: {layout: layout},
      success: function(response) {
        var new_html = response.html;
      },
     });     
  });
});
```

In `main.py`:

```
@app.route('/workstation')
def workstation():
  layout = flask.request.args.get('layout')
  return flask.jsonify({'html':flask.render_template('station.html',target=layout)})
```

Edit: you can store the value garnered from the `ajax` request in `flask.session`, and redirect to the desired page. To do so, create an additional route to save the value, and then utilize `window.location.replace` in the body of the `ajax` `success` function:

In `index.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.qtemp').on('click',function(){
    var layout = $(this).data('rep');
    $.ajax({
      url: "/update_layout",
      type: "get",
      data: {layout: layout},
      success: function(response) {
        window.location.replace('/workstation');
      },
    });     
  });
});
```

In `main.py`

```
import string, random

app.secret_key = ''.join(random.choice(string.printable) for _ in range(20))
#secret_key needed for session implementation

@app.route("/update_layout")
def update_layout():
  flask.session['layout'] = flask.request.args.get('layout')
  return flask.jsonify({'success':'True'})

@app.route('/workstation', methods=['GET'])
def workstation():
  return flask.render_template('station.html',target = flask.session['layout'])
```

Comment: What I want is to render a page with the layout variable as text on a ptag, and this is not doing that, this sends back the HTML contents(code) back to me

Comment: @silverhash `ajax` requests do not function as redirects, instead, they only return data to the current page sending the request (hence "dynamic"). To implement a pseudo-form post redirect, I added a solution whereby `flask.session` and an additional route serve as a means by which data can be saved across requests. In the body of the `success` function, a redirect is used.

Comment: I replaced my post request with a get request and turned my data to an object as you did now, the data is actually sent to flask finally..but that just about sums it up, the template is still not being rendered

Comment: @silverhash Is the page being redirected to `/workstation` after the click?

Comment: Yes, it is..with your edit..I can now redirect successfully but the layout variable doesn't seem to be sent to the station.HTML page, the problem now might be on my end I guess..Another thing, is the the correct way or are we hacking away here :D

Comment: @silverhash If you cannot use a traditional form POST with redirect, then this is a fine workaround, although I would not recommend it in place of a general form

Comment: It was an error on my end, your solution works buddy...thanks a tonne

Comment: @silverhash Glad to help!